# sharing data between two views in vaadin

Tags: vaadin7

I have tree structure like

- Tree base

  - Customer info
  - Password info

I have two different views for Customer info and password info.
But i want to access the data from customer info to password info. how can I do it?

I am loading two different views on click on tree node.
e.g if i click on customer info, then **CustomerInfo.java (view)** is loaded and if I click on password info, then **passwordInfo.java (view)** is loaded.

But in this case how can I access data loaded in customer info view?

Answer (score 0):

First, You will need Blackboard event system. On tree node click (probably inside tree value change listener), you fire an event with the data to be passed/shared as payload.

Second, modify your views to listen to this event. Inside the over-ridden listener method, access the payload of the event, and do what you want to do with it.

I Hope it helps.